# DataTables - use "OR" on multiple menu

Tags: jquery, datatables

My setup is as follows:

**MENU**

```
<select id="list">
  <option value="apple pie">Apple Pie</option>
  <option value="banana milkshake">Banana Milkshake</option>
  <option value="orange tart">Orange Tart</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('list').on('change', function(){
    table.columns( 11 ).search( this.value, false, false ).draw();
});
```

This works fine. However, how would I change this so if I use `multiple` in the menu it could look for "Apple Pie" OR "Banana Milkshake".... or any other combination of choices?

Answer (score 1):

Changing my JS to the following seems to have made it work

```
table.columns(10).search(myValues.replace(/,/g, '|'),true,false).draw();
```

Comment: It's curious, because `replace()` is a String function and you're applying to an array, but it works. I guess some of the functions make the conversion automatically. Do you have any idea of where the type is converted?

Comment: Yes, if `myValues` is `$(this).val()` this solution should produce an error. Here you have a fiddle where you can chek console and see it... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/25os5t4z/ You can use `.join()`instead. Or you're loading myValues with something different, of course.

Comment: Sorry! `var myValues = escapeRegExp($('#team-list').val().toString());` - the function escapes anything that the regex would normally use

Comment: Ok! Now it makes sense! ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you set the select as multiple, it gives you an array of values that you can join to use the smart search of datatables...

```
$('select#list').on('change', function() {
    table.columns(11).search($(this).val().join('|'),true,false).draw();
});
```

Here you have a fiddle with a working example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/p5t2247d/

I hope it helps

Comment: That will always search on the latest one rather than doing and "OR"

Comment: When you activate the multiple option, `$(this).val()` returns an array. Looping the array will search all options.

Comment: I need it to search OR - this only seems to search the last option I pass  to it

Comment: You're totally right. Sorry, I didn't realize you're using datatables. I've edited the answer (check also my comments to your solution)